# How to Embed Excel Files and Link Data into PowerPoint by python in specific place of slide

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter, python-pptx

There is an excel file with different sheets which is included by different charts and data.[image] I want to make a powerpoint for my daily presentation automatically by python(PPTx lib in python).

my problem is I have to copy the charts which exist in excel and past in my powerpoint which is created by python (pptx). I want to know is there any possibility to export charts from excel file to powerpoint by python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct API support for this in `python-pptx`. However, there are other approaches that might work for you.

Perhaps the simplest would be to use a package like `openpyxl` to read the data from the spreadsheet and recreate the chart using `python-pptx`, based on the data read from Excel.

If you wanted to copy the chart exactly, this is also possible but would require detailed knowledge of the Open Packaging Convention (OPC) file format and XML schemas to accomplish. Essentially, you would copy the chart-part for the chart into the PowerPoint package (zip file) and connect it to a graphic-frame shape on a slide. You'd also need to embed the Excel worksheet into the PowerPoint, perhaps repeatedly (once for each chart) and make any format-specific adjustments (Excel and PowerPoint handle charts slightly differently in certain details).

This latter approach would be a big job, so I would recommend trying the simpler approach first and see if that will get it done for you.

Comment: there is a problem for your first approach in my case, that the pptx do not support secondary axis charts. So in my case, I have to use XML?

Comment: Yes, although using direct `lxml` calls to add a secondary axis to a chart might be a lot simpler than the work to copy over the chart whole, so that hybrid approach might be worth considering first.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I do not have any idea about lxml .can you please give me a simple example to how we can use xml in python programming, especially to use secondary axis chart in pptx?

Comment: @sahand1372 sorry, that topic is much to large to try to summarize here. As I said, that approach would be a big job and would take a significant learning effort. If you search on "python-pptx workaround function" you'll see some examples and the lxml documentation is here: https://lxml.de/